# What can replace the with-statement

Tags: javascript, performance, functional-programming

What can replace the `with` statement, if you really need to change scope (i.e. to create REPL).

I tried something like:

```
function evalInScope( scope, code ) {    
    let 
    keys = scope.keys(),
    values = keys.map(it => scope[it]),
    fn = eval(`new Function( ${ keys.map(key => '"' + key + '"').join(',') }, " return (${ code })") `);
    return fn.apply(context, values);
}
```

But this does not seem the best solution

Comment: Can you give a little more context -- what is some example code that you want to remove the `with` from, and how do you expect the "after" syntax to look like?

Comment: for example, you can look on angular `$scope` expressions - `ng-init="$scope.test = true"` vs `ng-init="test = true"`, where $scope is a context scope. Then, imagine simple repl, where you need to eval user input in some sort of sandbox (but with full access to window object), like this: `var context = { func : function () {...} }, userInput = 'func()'; evalWith(context, userInput);`, without `with`-statement, user need to write `context.func()` insead of simply `func() `